# TD can't be nested inside TABLE

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I just noticed that I get the following warning/error from VS.

> Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'td' cannot be nested within element 'table'

I dare to claim that the element *TD* can too be nested inside *TABLE*. In fact, I say that it's the only correct way to use *TD*. What am I missing?

I've double and triple checked - no *TD* is nested inside any other *TD*. They're just inside *TR* which is inside *TABLE*.

## EDIT

```
<table>
  <td></td>
  @foreach (String t in ts)
  { <td>@t</td> }
  @foreach (String s in ss)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      @foreach (String t in ts)
      { <td>...</td> }
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the TD is nested inside a TR that's nested inside a TABLE? Maybe shows a bit of the HTML?

Comment: Can you show the markup? Maybe some missing closing tags...

Comment: Without seeing your HTML, what exactly is your problem? Will VS not let you compile? Are you getting odd results in your output? If you're sure your structure is correct, this is likely just VS lag.

Comment: @Superstringcheese No, everything works and looks like supposed to. That's why I'm surprised over the error. See my edit for mark-up.

Comment: The first line of your markup shows a TD directly within TABLE.

Comment: Same issue, but what caused it for me was I had some html before the <body></body> block.  Ooops. Once that line was moved inside the <body> block my <td> error went away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error suggests you are trying to do this:

```
<table>
    <td>...</td>
...
```

but `td`s must be nested in `tr`s like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
...
```

If you are already doing this, then you will need to show the HTML. Without seeing the HTML we can only guess...

Comment: I missed to add the first-line's *TR*. My bad.   :)

Comment: No worries, glad you found it

Answer (score 2):

The warning suggest that you have the td immediatly in table. td can be only withing tr tag